# ant exec task when command is fail

Tags: ant

I have some code:

```
<exec executable="src/main/webapp/bin/webdriver.bat" failonerror="true" resultproperty="return.code">
        <arg line="${ccc}/eeee--report-format JSON --report-file  testResultserer/resultere-data/wwwww.json"/>
    </exec> (1)
```

So, now I would like to exec command , when (1) are going fail.

How can I do this.

Comment: Don't understand your question, but suggest you read the "Windows Users" section of the exec manual page: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set property with the value of the return code and then execute the other command conditionally on the property's value:

```
<project>
  <exec executable="${cmd}" resultproperty="ret1"/>
  <condition property="cmd1failed" value="true">
    <not>
      <equals arg1="0" arg2="${ret1}"/>
    </not>
  </condition>
  <exec executable="echo" xmlns:if="ant:if" if:true="${cmd1failed}">
    <arg value="${cmd} failed"/>
  </exec>
  <exec executable="echo" xmlns:unless="ant:unless" unless:true="${cmd1failed}">
    <arg value="${cmd} didn't fail"/>
  </exec>
</project>
```

For example

```
$ ant -f exec.xml -Dcmd=/bin/true
Buildfile: /tmp/exec.xml
     [exec] /bin/true didn't fail

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
$ ant -f exec.xml -Dcmd=/bin/false
Buildfile: /tmp/exec.xml
     [exec] Result: 1
     [exec] /bin/false failed

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

This uses the if/unless attributes introduced with Ant 1.9.1.

If you are using an older version of Ant, you'll have to use separate targets, something like

```
<project default="both">
  <target name="cmd1">
    <exec executable="${cmd}" resultproperty="ret1"/>
    <condition property="cmd1failed" value="true">
      <not>
        <equals arg1="0" arg2="${ret1}"/>
      </not>
    </condition>
  </target>
  <target name="cmd1-fail" depends="cmd1" if="cmd1failed">
    <exec executable="echo">
      <arg value="${cmd} failed"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
  <target name="cmd1-pass" depends="cmd1" unless="cmd1failed">
    <exec executable="echo">
      <arg value="${cmd} didn't fail"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
  <target name="both" depends="cmd1-fail,cmd1-pass"/>
</project>
```

Comment: I want to do the following:
 when exit code(1) != 0 make build fail. Now I was modify my code:

...
<exec executable="src/main/webapp/bin/webdriver.bat" failonerror="false" resultproperty="testReturnCode">
        <arg line="${ccc}/eeee--report-format JSON --report-file  testResultserer/resultere-data/wwwww.json"/>
    </exec> (1)
..

<fail message="Test execution failure">
   <condition>
    <not>
     <equals arg1="${testReturnCode}" arg2="0"/>
    </not>
   </condition>
  </fail>
....
But also I haven't build fail.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want.  If you put you fail task where the `exec` with "failed" is my examples (including `ant:if` or a separate target) you will make the build fail.